# Django-allauth OAuth2 refresh token

Tags: django, django-allauth, oauth-2.0

When using django-allauth to do OAuth2 authentication, I can find the OAuth token using the following (bitbucket_oauth2 is the provider in the example):

```
account = user.socialaccount_set.get(provider="bitbucket_oauth2")
token = account.socialtoken_set.first().token
```

This token is only valid for an hour.  Where is the [refresh token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Refreshtokens) stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refresh token can be found in:

```
account = user.socialaccount_set.get(provider="bitbucket_oauth2")
refresh_token = account.socialtoken_set.first().token_secret
```